# How to access a function within another function on a string?

Tags: javascript, eval

In javascript, how to access function "look" in this sample.

This is the function:

```
var func = "(function() {function look() {return 12;};return 'OK'})()";
```

I try this

```
eval(func);
```

And return "OK", correct. But I need the return of the "look" funtion (return 12.
Is this possible?

Comment: Why aren't you returning `12` then? Why is your code in a string in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Change `return "OK"` to `return look()`.

```
var func = "(function() { function look() { return 12; } return look(); })()";
eval(func); // 12
```

Otherwise your `look()` function is never executed and, even if it currently was, you're returning the string `"OK"` anyway.

I'm not really sure why you're wanting to use `eval()` though. Why don't you simply:

```
var func = function() { function look() { return 12; } return look(); }
func(); // 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes!,

You can, Using closure you can achieve your answer.

var func="(function () { return function look() { return 12; } })()";

var cFun=eval(func);

cFun(); //12